# teradata to hive/ spark migration/performace

Tags: apache-spark, hive, teradata, data-migration

I have a few Teradata jobs that have SQL's with multiple joins  that run in  about 3 mins.
We are trying to get rid of Teradata for budget reasons,
and came up with an equivalent Hive job, it  takes 12-15 mins.
The record size is 2 million -10 million based on different days.  I am trying to figure out  the best and cheapest way to migrate from Teradata to any big data tool like Hive/Spark etc.
I know there are indexes etc built on Teradata tables, and hence the speed in Teradata.
Please advise on what I can try, I need to be very close to Teradata run times.

Answer (score 0):

Budget savings is multi-faceted.

1. Try to optimizing your hive/spark/flink first.

   - How many run times would spend if : `set hive.execution.engine=spark`
   - Need to analyze whether there have `data skew`, `small files`, the number of `mapper and reducer`，and so on
2. Try another engine like Apache Doris, Presto

Hope that helps.